# Reference for Unstable/Stable Manifold Theorem

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems

I'm looking for a reference to a proof of the theorem
 of stable / unstable manifolds , using the Hadamard method, ie, characterizing
the  stable / unstable manifolds locally as the graph of a differentiable function.

Comment: I am not sure about the way they were proved, but in Perko's "Dynamical systems" these theorems are nicely given, and the book is quite well-known

Comment: For what kind of situations ? Hyperbolic fixed point ? Invariant hyperbolic compact set ? Anyway, you should take a look at the book by Katok and Hasselblatt.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can find this proof in chapter $5$ of 
"Introduction to Dynamical Systems" 
by Michael Brin and Garrett Stuck. I highly recommend it.